C# 2-D array using for loop to output state and city on same line
Here is the question I was given:
Create a two-dimensional array to store the following states and their capitals and use a for loop to output each state and its capital on a separate line with spaces between the state and its capital.
Connecticut   Hartford
Delaware   Dover
Kentucky   Frankfort
Maryland   Annapolis
Massachusetts   Boston
Michigan   Lansing
New Hampshire   Concord
New Jersey   Trenton
New York   Albany
North Carolina   Raleigh
Pennsylvania   Harrisburg
Rhode Island   Providence
South Carolina   Columbia
Tennessee   Nashville
Virginia   Richmond
West Virginia  Charleston


I guess it's supposed to be a 16x2 array not a 2x16 array. Now I am unsure of how to get the state and capital to print on the same line together.


  

          string[,] places =
      { 
        {"Connecticut", "Hartford"},
        {"Delaware", "Dover"},
        {"Kentucky", "Frankfort"},
        {"Maryland", "Annapolis"},
        {"Massachusetts", "Boston"},
        {"Michigan", "Lansing"},
        {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
        {"New Jersey", "Trenton"},
        {"New York", "Albany"},
        {"North Carolina", "Raleigh"},
        {"Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"},
        {"Rhode Island", "Providence"},
        {"South Carolina", "Columbia"},
        {"Tennessee", "Nashville"},
        {"Virginia", "Richmond"},
        {"West Virginia", "Charleston"} 
      };
      for (int i = 0; i < places.GetLength(0); i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < places.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(places[i,j]);
        }
      }


Thank you!!

Why are you using a 2 dimensional array in the first place?  Using a Dictionary or a key value pair would be more practical and then you can just use a foreach loop.

You don't need to use nested loops here. That is why you getting 32 lines of output instead of 16. Because in the first dimension there is 16 elements, since there are two dimensions, outer loop will run two times, and each time it goes into inner loop and iterate 16 times.
You can simply do this:
string[,] places =  
{ 
    {"Connecticut", "Hartford"},
    {"Delaware", "Dover"},
    {"Kentucky", "Frankfort"},
    {"Maryland", "Annapolis"},
    {"Massachusetts", "Boston"},
    {"Michigan", "Lansing"},
    {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
    {"New Jersey", "Trenton"},
    {"New York", "Albany"},
    {"North Carolina", "Raleigh"},
    {"Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"},
    {"Rhode Island", "Providence"},
    {"South Carolina", "Columbia"},
    {"Tennessee", "Nashville"},
    {"Virginia", "Richmond"},
    {"West Virginia", "Charleston"} 
};

for (int i = 0; i < places.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{places[i, 0]}    {places[i, 1]}");
}


Dictionaries would be better to use in such a case but for i understand, you should use multiple dimensional array with two loops in order to do your task given by your teacher.
string[,] places =  
{
    {"Connecticut", "Hartford"},
    {"Delaware", "Dover"},
    {"Kentucky", "Frankfort"},
    {"Maryland", "Annapolis"},
    {"Massachusetts", "Boston"},
    {"Michigan", "Lansing"},
    {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
    {"New Jersey", "Trenton"},
    {"New York", "Albany"},
    {"North Carolina", "Raleigh"},
    {"Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"},
    {"Rhode Island", "Providence"},
    {"South Carolina", "Columbia"},
    {"Tennessee", "Nashville"},
    {"Virginia", "Richmond"},
    {"West Virginia", "Charleston"}
};


for  (int i = 0; i < places.GetLength(0); i++) // first dimension of array has 16 items, so this loop will be 16 steps
{
    for (int j = 0; j < places.GetLength(1); j++) // since the all values in array have two items, this loop will go for 2 steps. Each of two steps, Console.Write() function will print two related members next to each other in order.
    {
        Console.Write(places[i, j]+" "); // places[0,0] -> Connecticut, places[0,1] -> Hartford ---- for example.
    }
    Console.WriteLine(); // after the two members printed, you should skip one line in order to avoid other values be next to each other.
}

this would do. You just have to use Console.Write() function to print related values in a single line. And for the next step you should get to the next line with Console.WriteLine() function.

You want to iterate over the states once. Why do you have two for loops? Relatedly, i is assigned but never used. What is its purpose?

Oh my gosh wow... All the resources my teacher gave me said a 2-D array must use 2 for loops. It works great when I take out the first for loop. Thanks so much!

Well you took out all the cities when you edited the code. Here is what I changed it to:
    for (int j = 0; j < places.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"{places[0,j]}    {places[1,j]}");
    }


You do have to use two loops if you want to iterate over every element in the 2D array. But here you don't want to iterate over individual elements, you want to iterate over pairs of elements.

I guess I misunderstood what was wanted: It was supposed to be a 16x2 array not a 2x16 array. So now I have the state and capital as 2 elements in each array. Now I can't get them to print on the same line without an error.

Please, note that you in fact want a 1D array with pairs (State, Capital), i.e.
(string State, string Capital)[] places = {
  ("Connecticut", "Hartford"),
  ("Delaware", "Dover"), 
  ...
  ("West Virginia", "Charleston") 
};

foreach (var (state, capital) in places)
  Console.WriteLine($"{state} {capital}");

You have to represent these pairs with 2D array, but you still work with pairs: (places[i][0], places[i][1]) that's why you want a single loop:
string[,] places = ...

// Note, that place represents 1D array of pairs (State, Capital)
for (int i = 0; i < places.GetLength(0); ++i)
  Console.WriteLine($"{places[i][0]} {places[i][1]}");

